# Groups for M2M object based permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, many-to-many, django-queryset

I'm not 100% sure if this is just a terrible design on my part, or I'm not thinking clearly.

I'm utilising the `Group` model with a m2m relationship to `allowed_groups` on my `Category` model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """Forums are separated into Categories. A Category may hold many Forums"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    position = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    allowed_groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Select what usergroups are able to see this forum.",
        related_name='forum_categories',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

I originally attempted this with a m2m to the `User` model, however I quickly came to realise that it would become very tedious assigning what `Category` instances a `User` would be able to see every time a new `User` registered.

What I'm trying to achieve, is get the `Category` instances that a `User` should be able to see defined by what `Group` they are in.  The problem being, that they could potentially be within more than 1 `Group` at any given time.

I've tried to utilise the reverse `forum_categories` however if they are in more than one group it returns duplicates of `Category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct()` method removes duplicate categories from queryset. Try this:

```
Category.objects.distinct().filter(allowed_groups__in=user.groups.all())
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I did have `distinct()` in mind originally, but I didn't try the __in lookup with the groups reverse queryset.